# Host Mercurial on my company's intranet?

Tags: mercurial, hosting, intranet, bitbucket

Instead of using an external web-based Mercurial host, I want to set one up on my company's intranet. Is there a web-based tool for Mercurial that lets you have an interface like Bitbucket's but let's you host Mercurial locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mercurial ships with [`hgwebdir.cgi`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#multiple), which can be configured to provide a basic interface for repository hosting. It's quite straightforward to setup with Apache.

I use this on my OSX box at home; took about an hour - most of that was permissions related to kludging in server operations on a desktop box.

It's not Bitbucket. If you have a decent-sized budget, you might be able to purchase a bitbucket license for your company - I don't know.

Comment: Bitbucket now have a $10 one-time payment for up to 10 users. Might be enough. Just discovered it thanks to you mentioning the possibility to get it for the intranet.

Comment: Wrote too fast. This is only for git currently.

Answer (score 3):

[Hgwebdir](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) provides you a web interface for your hg repos. It's little simpler than what your can get from Bitbucket but good enough.

You have to setup a webserver(apache) and mercurial on a server.

Answer (score 1):

With [Deveo](https://deveo.com) you can manage Mercurial, Git and Subversion repositories, as well as WebDAV repositories for binary storage. It also has other features such as project Wiki's and issue tracking, which makes it like Github/Gitlab but with support for multiple VCS's.

(Disclaimer: I'm working at Deveo)

Comment: My opinion: Deveo it's very good!. But not for self-hosted choice, you pay an amount per user per year. it's lacks of "One time" payment to buy it. If they ever make a package for example to be able purchasing it for one year inlcuding updates only for that year will be the best.

Answer (score 0):

**[codeBeamer](http://www.intland.com/products/codebeamer)** is a complete Application Lifecycle Management platform that does everything that BitBucket and more. It comes with commercial support, and can be installed on any Java compliant server, also behind your company firewall.

The space is limited here to go into details, but the [codeBeamer user guide](https://codebeamer.com/cb/wiki/8798) should answer all your questions.

(Disclaimer: we are the developers of the product.)